# Why doesn't this argument show that every locally compact Hausdorff space is normal?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In proving that a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ is regular, we can consider the one-point compactification $X_\infty$ (this is not necessary, see the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209615/separating-a-point-and-a-closed-subset-in-a-locally-compact-hausdorff-space), but bear with me).  Since $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff, $X_\infty$ is compact Hausdorff.  As a result, $X_\infty$ is normal.

Imitating the idea in my proof in the link above and taking into consideration the correction pointed out in the answer, let $A,B\subseteq X$ be two disjoint, closed sets in $X$, and consider $X_\infty$.  Since $X_\infty$ is normal, there are disjoint open sets $U,V \subseteq X_\infty$ such that $A\subseteq U$ and $B \subseteq V$.  Then considering $X$ as a subset of $X_\infty$, we can take the open sets $U \cap X$ and $V \cap X$ as disjoint, open subsets of $X$ that contain $A$ and $B$, respectively...or so I thought.  I see from the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235729/locally-compact-hausdorff-space-that-is-not-normal) that this does not succeed in proving that a locally compact Hausdorff space is normal, since this is not true.

So my question is simply: why does the above proof fail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are closed in $X$. They need not be closed in the compactification $X_\infty$. You could try to fix this by replacing them with their closures in $X_\infty$, but then these need not be disjoint.

Comment: A specific example: The Tikhonov plank is the one-point compactification of the deleted Tikhonov plank $X$, which is not normal: the sets $H$ and $K$ of [this proof](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/21/the-tychonoff-plank/) of non-normality are closed and disjoint in $X$, but the extra point of $X^*$ is in the closure in $X^*$ of each of them.

Comment: I have made that kind of mistake before.  Maybe after making it this time I'll remember not to make it the next time!  Hopefully.  Thanks for the answer.